# How it write value="0" after clicked?

Tags: php

```
<form method="get">

    <button name="zero" value="0">0</button>

</form>

<?php 

if($_GET['zero']??NULL) { 
    echo $_GET['zero'];
}

?>
```

Why it don't work? 
Why zero does not want to write out?
Which function you use?

FILTER_INPUT, EMPTY.
Could any other?

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['zero']))`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your condition:

```
if($_GET['zero']??NULL) { 
    echo $_GET['zero'];
}
```

`$_GET['zero']??NULL` evaluates to `0` and that evaluates to `false` so you never enter your condition.

Using the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (`??`) in php 7 you can simply do:

```
echo $_GET['zero'] ?? NULL;
```

Which is the same as:

```
if (isset($_GET['zero']) {
   echo $_GET['zero'];
// } else {
//   echo NULL;
}
```

Comment: Click on the button he has me write a zero.